# How to create then assign inputs from first panel to different panel in one JFrame? And what's the mistakes in the formula?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton

```
       import javax.swing.*;
       import java.awt.*;
       import java.awt.event.*;
          
       public class Test extends JFrame{
       public static void main (String [] args){
//Components to be displayed on First panel
       
       JFrame frame = new JFrame("Insurance Calculation");
       frame.setVisible(true);
       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       frame.setSize(350,350); 
       JPanel panel = new JPanel();
       panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
       frame.add(panel);
                
       JLabel label1 = new JLabel ("Enter All Required Input");
       JLabel depositAmount = new JLabel("Enter Amount Deposited : ");
       JLabel yearsMature = new JLabel("Enter Years to Mature : ");
       JLabel insRate = new JLabel("Enter Interest Rate : ");
                
       JTextField depositTF = new JTextField(10);
       JTextField yearsTF = new JTextField(10);
       JTextField rateTF = new JTextField(10);
                    
       JButton button = new JButton ("Calculate");
                
       panel.add(label1);
                
       panel.add(depositAmount);
       panel.add(depositTF);
                
       panel.add(yearsMature);
       panel.add(yearsTF);
                
       panel.add(insRate);
       panel.add(rateTF);
                
       panel.add(button);
       button.addActionListener(new Action());
       }
            
            
       static class Action implements ActionListener{
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
//Shows result on another frame, but I actually want it to replace the content previously
                        
       JFrame frame1 = new JFrame("Insurance Calculation");
       frame1.setVisible(true);
       frame1.setSize(400,400);
                       
       double depositAmount;
       double yearsMature;
       double insRate;
       double total;
       double a;
       double b;
       double c;
                        
//Convert inputs from user to Double 
                        
       depositAmount = Double.parseDouble(depositTF.getText());
       yearsMature = Double.parseDouble(yearsTF.getText());
       insRate = Double.parseDouble(rateTF.getText());
                   
//Formula
                        
       a = 1 + insRate / 100;
       b = Math.pow(a,yearsMature);
       c = depositAmount * b;
                       
//Convert Double back to String in JLabel
                        
       depositTF.setText(Double.toString(depositAmount));
       yearsTF.setText(Double.toString(yearsMature));
       rateTF.setText(Double.toString(insRate));
       totalTF.setText(Double.toString(c));
        
//Components wanted to be displayed in second tab
                        
       JLabel label5 = new JLabel("Amount Deposited : " + depositAmount);
       JLabel label6 = new JLabel("Years : " +yearsMature);
       JLabel label7 = new JLabel("Interest Rate : " + insRate);
       JLabel label8 = new JLabel("Total Amount After 15 years: " + c);
       JButton button1 = new JButton ("Try Again");
       JPanel panel = new JPanel();
       panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
       frame1.add(panel);
                        
//adding all components into the panel
        
        panel.add(label5);
        panel.add(label6);
        panel.add(label7);
        panel.add(label8);
        panel.add(button1);
                      
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Your code doesn't even compile.  Rather than my completely rewriting your code, go through the Oracle tutorial [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Netbeans section.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advices, I will look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create one `JFrame` and one `JPanel` for your GUI.  Here's one way to do it.

[image: Compound Interest GUI]

As you can see, I separated the input fields and the output result with the Calculate `JButton`.  The maturity amount is in a non-editable `JTextField`.

To create the `JPanel`, I used a Swing [GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html).  The `GridBagLayout` is used to create a form-like `JPanel`, with `JLabels` on the left and `JTextFields` on the right.  I right-aligned the `JTextField` values for a better visual appearance.

Build your application one tiny tiny piece at a time.  Don't try and write 200 lines of code before your run your first test.  You'll wind up with a mess.

The first thing I did was make a call to the `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater` method.  This method ensures that the Swing components are created and executed on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

I separated the creation of the `JFrame` and `JPanel`.  The `JFrame` methods have to be called in a specific order.  This is the order I use for my Swing applications.  The `JPanel` Swing components should be created in column, row order.  This helps you to visually verify that the components are created and added to the `JPanel` correctly.

Your compound interest calculation was correct.  I modified it to compound the interest monthly, rather than yearly.

Here's the complete, runnable code.

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class CompoundInterestCalculator implements Runnable {

    private JTextField depositTF;
    private JTextField yearsTF;
    private JTextField rateTF;
    private JTextField totalTF;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new CompoundInterestCalculator());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Components to be displayed on First panel
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Compound Interest");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = createMainPanel();
        frame.add(panel);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Enter All Required Input");
        label1.setFont(panel.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 18f));
        panel.add(label1, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.gridy++;
        JLabel depositAmount = new JLabel("Enter Amount Deposited:");
        panel.add(depositAmount, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx++;
        depositTF = new JTextField(10);
        depositTF.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.TRAILING);
        panel.add(depositTF, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        JLabel yearsMature = new JLabel("Enter Years to Mature:");
        panel.add(yearsMature, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx++;
        yearsTF = new JTextField(10);
        yearsTF.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.TRAILING);
        panel.add(yearsTF, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        JLabel insRate = new JLabel("Enter Interest Rate:");
        panel.add(insRate, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx++;
        rateTF = new JTextField(10);
        rateTF.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.TRAILING);
        panel.add(rateTF, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        JButton button = new JButton("Calculate");
        panel.add(button, gbc);
        button.addActionListener(new CalculationListener());
        
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.gridy++;
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Total Amount at Maturity:");
        panel.add(label, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx++;
        totalTF = new JTextField(10);
        totalTF.setEditable(false);
        totalTF.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.TRAILING);
        panel.add(totalTF, gbc);
        
        return panel;
    }

    public class CalculationListener implements ActionListener {
        
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            double amount = valueOf(depositTF.getText().trim());
            double years = valueOf(yearsTF.getText().trim());
            double rate = valueOf(rateTF.getText().trim());
            
            if (amount == Double.MIN_VALUE 
                    || years == Double.MIN_VALUE 
                    || rate == Double.MIN_VALUE) {
                 totalTF.setText("Error");
                return;
            }
            
            // Compound interest (monthly)
            double a = 1.0 + rate / 100.0 / 12.0;
            double b = Math.pow(a, years * 12.0);
            double c = amount * b;
            String s = String.format("%,.2f", c);
            totalTF.setText(s);
        }
        
        private double valueOf(String number) {
            try {
                return Double.valueOf(number);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                return Double.MIN_VALUE;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing! It did help me out and solved my problems.